# Bash $(false) is true as a function argument

Tags: bash

I created a function to echo T or F.

```
tf() {
$1 && echo "T" || echo "F"
}
```

It seems to work...

```
tf true  # T
tf false # F
```

But then I want to use it for feedback when using the 'test' command. I pass it a test that should result in F for false:

```
tf $(test 4 -eq 3)  # T ?
```

But it comes back with a T for true!
What is this? I thought $() would substitute the result (false) in its place!

So I check to see what happens without the function; everything else being equal:

```
$(test 4 -eq 3) && echo "T" || echo "F"  # F
```

...and it's the correct answer; F for false. 4 does not equal 3.

So: why does command substitution of false become true when it is passed as an argument to a function?

Also I see that plain $(false) becomes true when it is passed as a function argument. But outside of a function, $(false) is correctly false:

```
tf $(false)  # T ?
$(false) && echo "T" || echo "F"  # F
```

How can I safely pass true-or-false-evaluating commands in to a function, and be sure that their true or false result will be dealt with correctly inside the body of the function? Is there some other formatting in which to wrap it?

Comment: You do understand that `$(...)` is *only* executed where it appears, right?

Comment: @Ignacio I'm not sure what you mean; could you elaborate?

Comment: `$(somecommand)` substitutes the *output* of somecommand at that point in the command line. Hint: try running `test 4 -eq 3` By hand -- what does it print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing things up here.

`test` only returns an exit code of `0 (TRUE)` or `1 (FALSE)`

You can easily check it by running:

`$(test 4 -eq 3)
echo $?`

You are trying to provide this value to a function
`tf $(test 4 -eq 3)` which does not work because $(test 4 -eq 3) does not return a value, only an exit code.

When you are trying it out manually it works, because `&&` and `||` [operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) are relying on exit code of previous command.

To make it work, you need to change the way you supply parameters to your function. For example like this (probably you'll want to split this up to a variable to make it readable):

`tf $(test 4 -eq 3 && echo true || echo false)`

Same happens with 'plain' `$(false)` as you mention below. When you execute true or false you will get an exit code of either `0` or `1`. They will not make it to the function, but work well with `&&` and `||` operators:
`$(false) && echo "T" || echo "F"`

Comment: So.. When I pass "true" and "false" to a function, it works because at that point they are commands-not-yet-executed, like passing a function name with no (). The "true" and "false" are executed or called within the function by the "if" statement. At that point they generate no value, just an exit code, which is acted on by the "if" statement. When I wrap false in $() it gets executed at that point, which is what @Ignacio meant. No value is produced, the exit code vanishes, "" is passed to my tf function, and the if statement accepts "" as truthy.

Comment: The statement does not accept "" as truthy, but rather `$1 && ...` works if $1 is not set at all.